# @Keyframes, atributo 'animation-delay' não funciona dentro de um 'from' ou 'to'

Tags: html, css, keyframes

Pretendo dar um 'delay' para essa animação mas não estou conseguindo da um atraso antes dela ir para o centro da página, se caso eu adicionar o 'animation-delay' dentro da class .ft ela já começa no centro da página ao carregar a mesma, queria que ao carregar a página ela começasse com um atraso antes de começar a ser exibida, deixando ela na mesma velocidade ao caminhar para o centro,  ??

```css
*{ padding:0px; margin:0px;}
body{background-color:#6C9;}

p.ft{ position: absolute; 
top:100px; 
left:300px; 
transition:all 0.5s linear;
font-size:40px;
color:#FFF;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.ft{ animation-timing-function:10s ease-in; 
animation-name:obj; 
animation-duration:3s;
}
                                    /*não funciona*/
@keyframes obj{ from{ left:-500px; animation-delay:5s;}
to{ left:300px;}
 }
```

```html
<p class="ft">ANIMAÇÃO MOVE</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara sua animação tinha alguns problemas, primeiro que na tag P tinha uma transição desnecessária, depois que os parâmetros do "animation" estavam meio errados. E o seu texto tinha um `left:300` antes do começar a animação por isso ela já começava no meio quando vc mexia no *delay*

Dei uma ajustada e a gora o texto demora `3s` antes de entrar na página e parar. Deixei uns comentários no código.

```css
*{ padding:0px; margin:0px;}
body{background-color:#6C9;}

p.ft{ position: absolute; 
top:100px; 

left:-500px; /*começa com o left negativo já*/
font-size:40px;
color:#FFF;
overflow:hidden;
white-space:nowrap;
}

.ft{ 

animation-name:obj; 
animation-duration:3s;  /*3s de duração*/
animation-delay:3s;  /*3s para começar*/
animation-fill-mode: forwards;  /*só roda 1x e para a animação*/
}
                                   
@keyframes obj{ 
from{ left:-500px;}
to{ left:300px;}
 }
```

```html
<p class="ft">ANIMAÇÃO MOVE</p>
```